# How to assign uint16_t value into uint8_t array?

Tags: c

I have the following data

```
uint16_t a[1] = { 0x2321 };
```

I want to convert to uint8_t as:

```
uint8_t b[1] = { 0x21 };
```

How can I do it in a C program?

Comment: Where is the question in this post.

Comment: @Griwes in the title.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I was pointing out a problem with question body, because the answer to my question that wasn't a question isn't really hard to give. You might've heard the term "sarcasm" before?

Comment: @Griwes yes I have, and you are quite bad at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast the lower byte:

```
uint16_t a[1] = {0x2321};
uint8_t b[1] = {(uint8_t)(a[0] & 0xFF)};
```

Comment: I don't know, that's a lot of masking and casting. Isn't just assigning the value to a `uint8_t` enough?

Comment: @MOehm yes No problem. Give it a try.

Comment: @MOehm, you at least need the cast, depending on your warning levels.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You mean a warning about truncating the data? With gcc, I get that only when I assign to literals, not when using variables as in the example here. The MS compiler cl warns me about literals (`/W2`) and shortening the data type (`/W3`). I'm a bit on the fence here whether I like the cast or not. It makes the intended shortening of data type clear, but it also seems a bit unnecessary, because the `uint8_t` is right there, on the same line. Probably better to leave it there.

Comment: @MOehm It is C, not Python, but the Python Zen says "Better explicit than implicit". A cast here documents what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bitmask to get the least significant byte:

```
uint8_t b[1];
b[0] = (a[0] & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
b[0] = a[0];
```

or in a declaration inside a function (this is not legal at file scope):

```
uint8_t b[1] = { a[0] };
```

There is a well-defined implicit conversion from unsigned intgral types to smaller unsigned integral types; the value is reduced modulo (1 + maximum value of the smaller type).

You don't need any casts or bitmask operations, although some compilers may give a specious (IMHO) warning about loss of precision if you don't write a cast to suppress this warning.